# Conductor of determinant of a Galois representation divides the conductor of the representation

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, characters, arithmetic-geometry, galois-representations

I already posted this question in MO but I'm going to repost it here as well.

I am studying [Serre's paper "Sur les représentations modulaires de degré 2 de $\mathrm{Gal(\overline{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q)}$"](https://www.college-de-france.fr/media/jean-pierre-serre/UPL5835292064138487263_Serre_Repr.modulaires_Galois.pdf) and I'm stuck trying to prove that $N(\det\rho)$ divides $N(\rho)$.

For context, consider a 2-dimensional Galois representation

$$\rho:\mathrm{Gal(\overline{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q)}\to \mathrm{GL}(V),$$
where $V$ is a 2-dimensional vector space over $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$.

Denote $G:=\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb Q)\cong\mathrm{Im}(\rho)$. We define the conductor of $\rho$ as

$$ N(\rho)=\prod_{\ell\neq p\text{ prime}}\ell^{n(\ell,\rho)},\quad \text{ where }\quad n(\ell,\rho)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{[G_0:G_i]}\dim(V/V_i), $$

and $G_i$ denotes the $i$-th ramification group of $G$, and

$$V_i=\{v\in V:\rho(\sigma)v=v\text{ for all }\sigma\in G_i\}. $$

We can also consider the homomorphism
$$ \det\rho:\mathrm{Gal(\overline{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q)}\to \overline{\mathbb{F}}_p^\times$$
as a 1-dimensional representation and associate its conductor.

I want to prove that $N(\det\rho)$ divides $N(\rho)$, which happens if and only if $n(\ell,\det\rho)\leq n(\ell,\rho)$. Since $\dim V=2$ and $\dim\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p=1$, the only case in which this is not clear is when $\dim{V_i}=2$; i.e., $V_i=V$.

Let $U=\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$, and define
$$ U_i = \{u\in U:\det\rho(\sigma)u=u\text{ for all }\sigma\in H_i\},$$
where $H_i$ is the $i$-th ramification group of $H\cong\mathrm{Im}(\det\rho)$.

We need to see that $U_i = U$ as well. But I have trouble proving the statement because I don't understand how the groups $G_i$ and $H_i$ are related. I'm not even sure if Serre is considering these ramification groups defined locally or globally.

I'm aware this is answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1217469/artin-conductor-of-a-character-and-factorisation-through-mathbbz-n-mathbb) and I'm aware that we can use the Kronecker-Webber theorem and CFT to prove it. But I'm trying to do it just as Serre suggest in his paper, comparing formulas of $N(\rho)$ and $N(\det\rho)$. If someone can give me a hint I would appreciate it a lot. Thank you so much.

Comment: Here is the MO post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/458316/conductor-of-determinant-of-a-2-dimensional-galois-representation-divides-conduc